# laravel: pass extra data to model based on password string when creating user / updating password?

Tags: laravel

I can call a `creating()` [event closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures) when a new model is created.
Can I pass/access extra data to/in that one?

Example: when I create / update a User model, I want to automatically create / update a password protected (encrypted) field, for which I need a password value. So, I want to pass on / have access to that password string.

The alternative is to do it manually and prepare the result in advance and pass all to create(), e.g.:

```
User->create([
  ...,
  'password' => Hash::make($password),
  'secret' => someEncryptFunction('mysecret', $password),
  ...,
]);
```

But I was hoping to achieve this as "part of" the model.

**Update 2**: Now exploring the Jetstream / Fortify route. Have the feeling that is the cleanest place, because that's where `$input['password']` is available and the `User::create()` takes place. Looking at `app\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser.php`, `UpdateUserPassword.php` and `ResetUserPassword.php`. Need to look into this more. Not clear yet what the cleanest way is to add my `Secret` as an optional feature (similar to how 2 factor is an optional feature).

**Update 1**: can I do something similar as for a factory?

```
class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition()
    {
      ...
    }

    /**
     * Add secret field based on user's password.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
     */
    public function addSecret(string $passwordString = 'password')
    {
        $secret = createSecretField($passwordString);

        return $this->state( fn(array $attributes) => [
          'secret_field'=>$secret,
        ]);
    }

}
```

So I can use:

```
$fields = [
  'password' => 'mypassword',
  ...
];
User::factory()->addSecret($fields['password'])->create($fields);
```

Was thinking of using regular model methods / attribute mutators, but not sure that is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, then yes, as you can see in the documentation you referenced.

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::created(function ($user) {
      $user->password = 'do whatever'
    });
}
```

You will have the access through (in this case), $user, and then you can do in the callback whatever you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. Don't want `created()` (in my case: `creating()`) to *define* the password, but to *have access* to it. $user->password in the model is filled with the hashed password, so: how to access / pass on the string password?

Comment: Are you aiming for setting password to be whatever you want it to be, or to have user log in and then to instantly receive their password in plain text?

Comment: Trying to separate the regular app create/update User model from the “create/update password protected field that uses the same password”